# How to store/remember the data fetched from ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsp

I'm retrieving some data into a JSON array, then display it into an HTML table which contains some data enclosed within hyper links. i.e. a couple of the columns' data are clickable, once clicked it displays another JSP page (say page #2) with some more data which was kept on the JSON array itself.

Now this page 2 has a 'Back' button functionality - the expected behavior is when user clicks the 'Back' button it should go back to page 1 where the HTML table data was displayed and user should be able to see the data which they first fetched too. i.e. there should be some way to remember the data fetched from my initial AJAX request and retrieve the same data which user fetched in page 1 when they go back to that page from the child page#2.

Th AJAX call is triggered when user enters an account# and the type of account - I fetch data accordingly and get the result in the 'response' object and neatly display it on html table, but after user moves from that page and again hits the back button I see the page#1 without the table. Now again I cannot ask the user to re-enter the details to see the data that they retrieved earlier. It's pretty annoying.

Please give me a solution to this problem. Thanks All.

Appreciate for taking time to read this.

Here's a part of the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var flag = "1";

    $('#accountType').bind('change', function (event) {

        var accountType = $('#accountTypeSelect').val();
        var account = $('#accountText').val();

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}' + "/Page1.spr", //request page
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                "accountType": accountType,
                "account": account,
                "flag": flag
            }, //data sent to request page    
            success: function (response) {
                // code to display the data into the html table
            },

            error: (function (message) {
                console.log("error message : " + message);
            }),

            statusCode: {
                404: function () {
                    alert("page not found");
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: @neshpro9 how does storing the response is a duplicate of getting the response..?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the data in `HTML5` `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` using the `setItem` method as follows:

```
success: function(response) {
     sessionStorage.setItem("result", response)
     // code to display the data into the html table
}
```

And access it later using the `getItem()` When you come back to the page like

```
var prevResponse = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("result"));
if(prevResponse)
  {
    // code to be executed when old dats is found
  }
else{

}
```

Ideally you code in first pages load will be something like

```
var prevResponse = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("result"));
if(prevResponse)
{
    // data exists : code to be executed when old dats is found
}
else{
  jQuery.ajax({}) // send the AJAX request to fetch data
}
```

You can read more about session and local Storage [here](https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-definitive-guide-david-flanagan-6th/chapter-20/localstorage-and-sessionstorage)

[Browser support](http://caniuse.com/namevalue-storage) for web storage API.

**Update**

If you don't have `HTML5` support, you could use [jQuery cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin (*There are plenty of others as well*) for storing data at client side.

You can store data into a cookie as follows:

```
$.cookie("result", response);
```

Then to get it from the cookie like:

```
$.cookie("result");
```

Comment: Your answer is purely about `html5` . please help the user appropriately as it is tagged under jsp . why could you post about session in jsp

Comment: @SanKrish well i updated the answer mentioning `html5`. I didn't even notice the `jsp` tag until now. Doesn't `jsp` support `html5` doctype? i'm a fronted developer, i answer based on what i know. How could i/ why should i post about something i'm not much familiar with? Feel free to add the another answer if you think it's more appropriate.

Comment: It is not about answering it could have been more appropriate if the user tagged it under `html` as you have explained about it . As it is under jsp tag , he might be expecting more of server side stuff . so your answer might be mis-leading . but i am not quite sure on this til we hear it from the questioner

Comment: @SanKrish You didn't answer my question: Doesn't jsp support html5 doctype? *"he might be expecting"* you're now making assumptions. My answer is one way to get the job done as far as i know. Why are you desp about it? how exactly is it *mis-leading*? If it is, then please lead the OP in the right direction mentioning why this is mis-leading instead of wasting your time commenting.

Comment: _Doesn't jsp support html5 doctype?_ `html5` is browser dependent and off course  jsp supports it

Comment: @SanKrish exactly. Then my answer is valid regardless of the `jsp` tag.

Comment: but as per my opinion  _You can save the data in HTML5 sessionStorage or localStorage using the setItem method as follows:_ is must to guide the user as it can be done through javascript also

Comment: @SanKrish what do you mean "it can be done through javascript also"?? that is javascript. I've no idea what you're onto.

Comment: i meant it through native js . what if the browser doesnt support html5 will it work

Comment: @SanKrish that is why i mentioned `HTML5` in my answer in response to your comment. And here is the [BROWSER SUPPORT](http://caniuse.com/namevalue-storage), it is supported from IE8, if that makes you feel any better. My answer only covers html5 supported browsers. Now hopefully you can move on.

Comment: gud answer on the whole now

Comment: thanks all for taking the time to respond!! @Tilwin Joy I'm not sure whether my application server will support HTML5, I use Websphere 8.0 running on IBM RAD8.0.3. My intention of posting this question is to get an approach/method to display the data previously fetched by an ajax request. My pages are built with JSP and we use HTML 4. I expect a client side solution which can be integrated into my existing code easily so that I can make my page ready asap.

Comment: @T J Can you provide a solution without using HTML5?

Comment: @T J the cookie is not being set. I suppose it's because the type of response I receive. My response is an json array which looks something like    ' {"01" : {"userId" : "blablabla", "account#" : 12345, "field3" : value3...}}. If I give any basic String as value of the cookie it is being set, any idea on how to set these kind of json response into a cookie? Should I be using different cookies (cookie1, cookie2 etc) to set each of the response object ?

Answer (score 0):

You maybe can use cookie via jquery. But user have to enable the browser's cookie. It usually enabled by default setting.

To add:

```
$.cookie("key1", data1);
$.cookie("key2", data2);
```

To read:

```
$.cookie("key1");
```

To delete:

```
$.removeCookie("key1");
```

So, you can try to read cookie to load table data, if no data, call ajax:)

Answer (score -1):

Another way is to save it in a hidden input:

```
success: function(response){
      $("#hiddenInput").val(JSON.stringify(response));
}
```

Comment: yeah, cause that lasts across page views .. :P

Comment: In this case, you are right, but if he is already using JQuery, he may also use JQuery modal.

Comment: How does jquery modal help him preserve data in input type=hidden across pageviews with back button?

Comment: If he use jquery modal, he wouldn't need a back button, but a close button.